# Render array of objects to list in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I try to convert an array of objects into a list. For now, I just want to convert a "type" property of my object into a list item, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.travelRawdata = [{type:15}];
}
render(){
    return(
        <ul>
           {this.travelRawdata.forEach(element => <li>{element.type}</li>)}
        </ul>
);}
```

I don't get any output. If I use `console.log(element.type)` it works fine, so I think there is something wrong with my HTML tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will always return `undefined`. You want to use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, to convert your data into an array of react elements:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.travelRawdata = [{type:15}];
}
render(){
    return (
        <ul>
           {this.travelRawdata.map(element => <li>{element.type}</li>)}
    </ul>
    );
}
```

**Note:** Be sure to read up [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) on lists and keys. Not including a key for the element, results in rerenders for every single element every time the array is updated.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
this.travelRawdata.map((item)=> { return (<li>{item.type}</li> })
```