# Looping <li> elements in JSX React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx

In React.js documentation, I wonder how `Array.map()` is used in JSX React.

```
function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      {number}
    </li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}
```

in `<ul>` tag, why we just put the variable `listItems` directly?. Because I think it will return a single array instead of `<li>` elements like this :

```
<ul>
[
<li></li>,
<li></li>,
<li></li>,
]
</ul>
```

how does JSX treat an array?
Did I have to loop `listItems` manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708941/render-array-of-objects-to-list-in-jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to take a look here: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-loop-in-react-jsx/ . I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The **map()** method is the most commonly used function to iterate over an array of data in JSX. You can attach the map() method to the array and pass a callback function that gets called for each iteration. When rendering the User component, pass a unique value to the key prop.

Answer (score 0):

JSX treat an array like a multiple elements. You can code like this:

```
function NumberList() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Or use an array. But when use an array, we need to add an unique `key` attribute for each element in array:

```
function NumberList() {
  const listItems = [
    <li key="1">1</li>,
    <li key="2">2</li>,
    <li key="3">3</li>,
  ];

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}
```

If you want to using one element, you can wrap all elements to a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
function NumberList() {
  const listItems = (
    <>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}
```

Use map is same as using array:

```
function NumberList() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      {number}
    </li>
  );

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}
```

or using map directly in JSX:

```
function NumberList() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        numbers.map((number) =>
          <li key={number.toString()}>
            {number}
          </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

About `key` attribute, please refer to React's document: (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)[https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys].